# How do I make a RegionPlot for a matrix?

Tags: matrix

I have a 9 x 8 matrix containing values 0, 1, 2 and 3. I want to plot the region of matrix with value 3 with my parameters `x -> {0, 0. 4}` and `y -> {0, 200}`.

Comment: Would you please make clear what your "parameters" are supposed to mean?

Comment: I have solved basically 8 non linear equations by varying 2 parameters and stored the number of solutions in this matrix. I want to plot the region of my parameters where number of solution are 3.

Comment: And the parameter `x` has changed gradually from 0 to 0.4 and y has changed from 0 to 200?

Comment: yes. I did try the code given by you but the plots are really thin.

Comment: Have another look. I added how to use `AspectRatio`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `A` is your matrix, you should try

```
MatrixPlot[1 - Unitize[A - 3]]
```

`ArrayPlot` is another alternative. You may find also the `DataRange` option of `MatrixPlot` and `ArrayPlot` interesting. For example (with reasonable `AspectRation`):

```
MatrixPlot[1 - Unitize[A - 3], DataRange -> {{0, 0.4}, {0, 200}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

plots the matrix scaled to the aspect ration `300/0.4`. Of course, that won't be very helpful as the resulting plot is very thin.

To obtain a `MeshRegion`, you may also use

```
ArrayMesh[1 - Unitize[A - 3], DataRange -> {{0, 0.4}, {0, 200}}]
```